# Exception : java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol while reading json via POSTMAN

Tags: java, json, post, postman

I am trying to read simple json object in the Java program below:

```
public class Hello{

@POST
@Path("/jsonRequest")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getJson(String url) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    JSONObject json= readJsonFromUrl(url);
    Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(json);
    return response.build();
}
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    return json;
}
```

However, when I try to give a POST request via POSTMAN I get the following error:

```
   javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;pallavi&quot;,
&quot;location&quot;:&quot;Bangalore&quot;}
```

The POSTMAN request looks like:[image]

Can someone please help me identify where exactly am I going wrong? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: As the error says, `url` is not an URL. It contains a `JSONObject`, so you cannot do `new URL(url)`

Comment: Then what is the alternative?

Comment: `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(url)`

Comment: Now I get another exception : javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments